# How to perform the animation sequence with delay in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uianimation

We have seven buttons, on clicking of anyone among them, i need to perform animations on remaining buttons "in sequence".
At present am using the following code in for loop,but animation is done on all the buttons at once.

```
 [UIView beginAnimations: @"Fade In" context:nil];
 button.alpha = 0;
 [UIView setAnimationDelay:0];
 [button setTitle:@"helloworld"  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 [UIView setAnimationDuration:0];
 button.alpha = 1;
 [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: change the animationdelay and its duration time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not use beginAnimations:context: any more. To quote Apple's docs:

> Use of this method is discouraged in iOS 4.0 and later. You should use
>   the block-based animation methods to specify your animations instead.

Use the new animateWithDuration family of methods instead. Specifically `animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:`. That method takes a delay parameter. You can issue a series of animation commands, each with a larger delay value. You can also chain animations by making the completion block of each animation trigger the next animation.

Edit: here is a link to a post where I show code that uses the completion method to trigger a sequence of animations one right after the other:

[Scrolling the array of images using the CABasicAnimation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10352179/scrolling-the-array-of-images-using-the-cabasicanimation/10574425#10574425)

Comment: Block-based UIView animations' completion blocks don't get called if interrupted for example user leaving the app etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try this thing in for loop

```
for(int btnIndex = 0; btnIndex < 7; btnIndex++) {

  UIButton *button = [buttons objectAtIndex:0]; //get button reference from an array

  [UIView beginAnimations: @"Fade In" context:nil];
button.alpha = 0;
  [UIView setAnimationDelay:(0.1 * btnIndex)];
  [button setTitle:@"helloworld"  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.1];
button.alpha = 1;
  [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```