# Swift UIAnimation blocked by for loop

Tags: swift, asynchronous, async-await, dispatch

I have a UIAnimation that pulls out a message log, but I need to populate the message log using a for loop as well. I have the animation taking place before the for loop begins, however, the animation doesn't actually begin until after the for loop finishes executing (even though the loop is located after the UIAnimation).

I've tried putting the contents of the for loop within an autoreleasepool (did not work)

I've tried running the for loop on a background thread, however, most of the code within the loop needs to be executed on the main thread, and I haven't had success with that approach.

The for loop is very large, and most of the code is irrelevant to the question, so you can set this up using any UIAnimation, and any relatively time consuming for loop...

for example:

```
let someView = UIView(frame:CGRect(x:self.view.frame.size.width,y:0,width:self.view.frame.size.width,height:self.view.frame.size.height))
someView.backgroundColor = .red
UIView.animate(withDuration:0.3,animations:{
    self.someView.frame.origin.x = 0
})

//You can wrap this with something like:
//DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async(execute: {
//But this^ doesn't work on the majority of the code within the loop
for i in 0...1000{
    print("hopefully this loop takes a few seconds to finish executing")
    print("mainthread tasks being executed")
    print("populating UITable in my particular case, and rendering Images/Video/text")
}
```

The closest that I can get to making it better is to add a "completion" to my UIAnimation, (which will allow the UIView to pull out completely/immediately) but then there is still a second of wait time before the first messages appear...

Also, I am populating a UITableView within the for loop. Not sure if that has any extra relevance to the primary issue I'm having or not...

I'm pretty familiar with DispatchQueue and the differences between async/sync. If you have any potential solutions, or ideas, please let me know.

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23912993/how-to-perform-the-animation-sequence-with-delay-in-ios might give you some idea

Answer (score 0):

The animation does not happen immediately, when you call `UIView.animate`. In stead all the animations are collected and run at some appropriate time. This is why the animation only starts *after* your for loop is done.

So the way to fix it is to get the animation to run *before* your `for` loop runs. Now, accepting what you say, that the `for` must run on the main thread, you have a number of options. You could put the `for` loop inside a `DispatchQueue.main.async{}` or somehow throttle it down so that the animation gets going first. Your idea of using the completion is a good one but you mention some practical issues you picked up with it. So either solve those practical issues, try to run the `for` inside a `DispatchQueue.main.async{}` or even, based on practical considerations, start the `for` loop on the main thread but somewhere else, say in something like `didLayoutSubviews` (fixed) or as now together with the animation but after a few millis delay to allow the animation to get going.

Comment: The DispatchQueue.main.async{} didn't work, I'm going to have to try to do better pre-loading or something... I haven't heard of didLayoutComponents and I can't find it on google... Did you mean didLayoutSubviews?

Comment: Hi - yes sorry I wrote that off the cuff. I think the best option is to do something in the completion block. It will force you to really think it through and in the others you sort of hope for the best. Anyhow, I am surprised the Dispatch ... did not work. I think if you dispatch it after a pause it should work. The animations get scheduled on the main queue and you want the loop to be scheduled after that which I why I think completion is best. But a pause should do it as well and maybe didLayoutSubviews under the right conditions.

Comment: The main thing here is that the animations gets scheduled - they don't execute immediately. And you want to schedule your ```for``` to also execute on the main loop but after the animations started. This can be quite tricky - I was looking for some notification that gets sent when the animations starts or ends but did not find any. I did not look into it deeply but some message such as didLayoutSubviews may be messaged after the animations and then bob is your uncle! But again I think best is to do it somehow through the completion block.

Answer (score -1):

It's an interesting question. This made me think!

Yes, you mentioned that you understand differences between async/sync but didn't mention if you tried animating in the main thread.

Did you try putting the
`UIView.animate(...)` in `DispatchQueue.main.async{}`?

Comment: Yeah, the whole function is being executed from the main thread anyway so that is why it wouldn't have any effect for me. I did test that just to be sure.

Comment: Okay. Did you try these cases for `for` loop?  `.userInitiated`, `.userInteractive`